# Singleton Pattern time of object instantiation

Tags: java, singleton

This may seem like a silly question, but I was wandering when creating a class following the singleton pattern, at what point is the object instantiated?

e.g. `private static SingleObject instance = new SingleObject();`

with the method `getInstance()` defined by:

```
public static SingleObject getInstance(){ 
    return instance; 
}
```

So 'instance' is a static variable which refers to an instance of SingleObject. But at what point is it actually instantiated and loaded into memory? (If that makes any sense)

Comment: Check wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern.

Comment: Sorry first line of my first comment was wrong. it will be instantiate if you call the `getInstance` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's instantiated the time the class is loaded (that's the time static members are initialized), which is the first time any reference to this class is made. If `getInstance` is the only member exported by this class (i.e. the only method or member accessible from outside this class), the instance is created the first time `getInstance()` is called.

Comment: I was just thinking, if you have an 'instance' as above which has a reference to an instance of SingleObject, so it can access non-static methods/data. But because the variable is static, can it access the static data as well? If so, is this the only case where an instance can access static methods/data?

Comment: @Paldan An instance can always access static methods/data of its own class (and of other classes if the access modifiers allow). It's the other direction that doesn't work (accessing non-static data/methods from a static method).

Answer (score 1):

It depends. A typical implementation of the Singleton pattern looks like:

```
class SingleObject {
    private static SingleObject instance;

    private SingleObject(){
    }

    public SingleObject getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new SingleObject();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

in which case it's instantiated on the first call to `getInstance`. But there's no universal rule as to when it needs to be done. A Singleton could also be implemented as:

```
class SingleObject {
    private static SingleObject instance = new SingleObject();

    private SingleObject(){
    }

    public SingleObject getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

in which case it would be instantiated when the class loads. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) has a few examples of different implementations.

Comment: The OP is using your second implementation.